# Control util.inspect's behaviour when it is called by util.format

Tags: node.js

http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format

> ```
> util.format('%s:%s', 'foo'); // 'foo:%s'
> ```
>
> If there are more arguments than placeholders, the extra arguments are converted to strings with `util.inspect()` and these strings are concatenated, delimited by a space.

I'm using this `util.format` but I want to control the behaviour of the `util.inspect` it calls automatically. Specifically, passing it the `depth:null` option.

Is there a way to do it?

---

Monkey-patching `util.inspect` doesn't work because `util.format` internally calls it just `inspect`

```
function (f) {
  if (typeof f !== 'string') {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      objects.push(inspect(arguments[i]));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll just have to `util.inspect` elements manually before feeding them into `util.format`

```
for(var k in str)
    if (typeof str[k] !== 'string')
        str[k] = util.inspect(str[k], {depth:null})
util.format.apply(null, str);
```